# cordova android app works on emulator but does not connect to server when running on device

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, cordova-plugins

I have build android app on cordova -v9, it works completely fine till android 8 but when run on android 9 it only runs on emulator fully functional but when run on real android device, final submission of data to database is not done. Problem is I don't see any error in it. I think ajax request is not completed with database. Can anyone suggest some solution to it.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the error and what protocol you are using http or https?

Comment: probably the problem is in the protocol: are you using `http://`?

Comment: yes i m using http:// but also tried with https:// it doesn't worked.

Comment: @Swayangjit error is that on submitting data to datbase, the ajax request doesn't works i.e data is not submitted to database. Alltough the app functions well on android studio emulator.

Comment: are all API is working or only single API is failing ?

Comment: @Swayangjit only single API is failing i.e data is not submitted to database, rest everything functions fine